# Entity Framework Include related table when table is empty

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1

I'm reading data from database to gridview's datasource. My Table2 can be empty. When I try to bind columns from Table2 gives me error that doesn't contain that column. I checked the data that was coming from query. There is Table2 but not columns. Just Count = 0.

How can i get columns of related table even if it is empty?

```
return entities.Table1
        .Include("Table2")
        .Include("Table3  ")
        .Include("Table2.Table4")
        .Where(results => results.ID == anotherId)
        .ToList();

Table1  one to many  Table2
Table3  one to many  Table1
Table4  one to many  Table2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use EF Table1, Table2, etc. are all classes. `Include(string)` method is used for caching related records in one query. You can remove `Include` statements and your query will work  similar. So if you don't have any realted records in your DB between Table1 and Table2, then you get count = 0 for Table2 property.

Add some related records to your DB to Table1 and Table2 and execute your query again. Table2 is not `DataSet` or `DataTable`, but class.

I think event that `.Include("Table2")` is redundant if you use `.Include("Table2.Table4")`

Notice, that Table2 should have FK to Table1 if you want one-to-many relation.

**EDITED**

If you use EF you don't have to use joins to collect data from few tables. But you have to have FKs well defined. You just use `var collction = table1.Table2` to get all Table2 objects related to table1 object.

Comment: There is foreign keys for tables. I want to show some data from these tables. when user enters data for table1 record it will be saved to table2. Table1 has definitions and Table2 will have data for those definitions.

Comment: As I wrote before, please add some records to Table1 and Table2 manually and execute your query again.

Comment: Oh, i was thinking like tables. Now i understand how it comes from entity. just collections. Should i use joins in ef to get results just like sql join queries?